# How to display the expectedTravelTime in the center of a route on MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I want to display a white rectangle with the expected travel tim in the center of a specified route on the MKMapView.

Comment: Why they down rated my question, it was really an issue and i solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code i used to get the ETA & center point of the route, you can use the ETACoordinate and create custom Annotation view and add it to the map

-(void) showRouteBetweenSourceCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) sourceCoordinate destinationCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) destinationCoordinate onMapView:(MKMapView*) onMapView onCompletion:(void(^)(NSString *ETA,CLLocationCoordinate2D ETACoordinate,NSError *error)) onCompletion
{

```
MKDirectionsRequest *request =
[[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];

MKPlacemark *sourcePlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:sourceCoordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *sourceMapItem=[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:sourcePlacemark];
request.source = sourceMapItem;

MKPlacemark *destinationPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:destinationCoordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *destinationMapItem=[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlacemark];
request.destination = destinationMapItem;

request.requestsAlternateRoutes = NO;
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];

MKDirections *directions =
[[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         onCompletion(nil,CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0),error);
     } else {

         if (response.routes.count>0) {


             MKRoute *route=response.routes[0];

             MKMapPoint routePoint=route.polyline.points[route.polyline.pointCount/2]; // get the center point of the polyline

             [onMapView addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];

             CLLocationCoordinate2D etaCoordinate=MKCoordinateForMapPoint(routePoint);

             int etaInMins=(int)(route.expectedTravelTime/60);

             onCompletion([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d min",etaInMins],etaCoordinate,nil);

         }
         else
             onCompletion(nil,CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0, 0),nil);

     }
 }];
```

}